# Will I need to register two new domain names?

Tags: subdomain, domain-name

For example, I have a domain name `www.example.com`. Now, I need `part1.example.com` and `part2.example.com` as well. Does this require me to register two more domain names? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, whichever service you registered your domain name through should allow you to edit your domain entry.  Just update your atable entries there.  What you are referring to is called a sub-domain and it is part of the same domain you registered already.

Here is the link on the GODADDY help for subdomain management.
http://help.godaddy.com/article/4652

Answer (score 2):

No, you must set a **subdomain** for your domain example.com.

Answer (score 0):

You better try to have a sub-domain. That will work for you. You can set it in your control panel or else you can do it with your .htaccess file.

Hope it would work for you

Answer (score 0):

For each subdomain you need to add an A record to the DNS information for your domain. You can usually do this through your registrar's online control panel.

You'll also need to configure your webserver to recognize which subdomain is being used, or else it'll serve up the same content for different subdomains. Your web host may not support this.

It would probably be best to bring this up with the support people at whatever web host you're using; SO probably won't be much help with your specific situation unless you're running the webserver yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will need access to the DNS configuration in order to add a new CNAME (Alias) to your zone file. For example, GoDaddy provides a DNS Manager where you can very easily add aliases to your domain. Note that it usually takes some time (perhaps hours) for the new sub-domain to be propagated to the DNS servers.

Check out their article on the subject. Although this is about GoDaddy, the concept applies to most Domain Registers.

http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/4080

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to purchase additional domains for what you are trying to do. You are referring to sub-domains and we allow you to make up to 40 of them with Standard DNS and allow unlimited sub-domains with our Premium DNS. To create a sub-domain please see: http://x.co/YPR1 ^Colby Go Daddy Social Media Team

Comment: No need to post short URL's. See [Markdown help: Links](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links). Then we don't need to guess where we'll end up.